# Integrate JSHint into Jenkins without using the Checkstyle or JSLint reporter

Tags: jenkins, jshint

Is it possible to integrate JSHint into Jenkins without using the Checkstyle or JSLint reporter?

The reason why I want to do this is because both reporters by default also show *non-errors*, which is not what I want (see also [JSHint shows non-errors for checkstyle reporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194681/jshint-shows-non-errors-for-checkstyle-reporter)).

Is there a way to integrate JSHint directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to point out that jsHint will now work with the Report Violations, but you must set the report type to `jslint-xml`. Here is a sample for the Ant task:

```
<jshint dir="${js.dir}">
     options="${jshint.options}">
     <include name="**/*.js"/>
     <exclude name="**/*.min.js"/>
     <report type="jslint-xml"/>
</jshint>
```

Use the violations plugin for Jenkins, and put the name of your `_jsHint_ XML output in the space for`jslint`.

And, it's actually documented in the `README.md` too. I missed it.

Answer (score 13):

I had similar problem last week, but I use grunt to run jshint. I simply override jshint options, here is example code:

```
jshint: {
    options: {
        jshintrc: '../config/.jshintrc',
    },
    src1:  [
        'file1.js',
        'file2.js'
    ],
    src2: [
        'source/file3.js',
        'source/file4.js'
    ],
    jenkins: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '../config/.jshintrc',
            reporter: 'checkstyle',
            reporterOutput: 'jshint.xml',
        },
        src: [ "<%= jshint.src1 %>", "<%= jshint.src2 %>" ]
    },
}
```

So when you want run jslint on jenkins you simply run:

```
grunt jshint:jenkins
```

and output is generated to .xml file. I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternate way of implementing @mateusz's excellent answer. Instead of creating an additional target that combines all files with the extra report options, override the report and output only when `--jenkins` is passed in.

```
var JENKINS = grunt.option('jenkins');

...

jshint: {
    options: {
        jshintrc: '../config/.jshintrc',
        reporter: JENKINS && 'checkstyle',
        reporterOutput: JENKINS && 'jshint.xml'
    },
    src1:  [
        'file1.js',
        'file2.js'
    ],
    src2: [
        'source/file3.js',
        'source/file4.js'
    ]
}
```

Not only does it avoid repeating the files, but in some cases you *cannot* combine them all into a single task. In our case, we use different `.jshintrc` files for sources vs. tests. A side benefit to this method is that you can easily apply the option to other tasks without repeating it for each.

```
$ grunt jshint --jenkins
```